# Glassfish how to prevent direct access to a html file

Tags: html, .htaccess, glassfish

I am running glassfish 3.1
Say I have 2 html files: a.html b.html and their urls are:

```
http://localhost:8080/mysite/a.html
http://localhost:8080/mysite/b.html
```

I only want a user to click a link from within **a.html** to get to **b.html.** if a user try to directly access b.html using `http://localhost:8080/mysite/b.html`, he should be redirected back to a.html.

How do i achieve this? I read something about .htaccess file. Does glassfish support this where should I find this file and modify it to suit my needs as stated above?

Comment: glassfish is a web application server.  Are a.html and b.html simple html files?  If so, you may be happier with something like apache web server.  That said, b.html should look at the [Referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) and issue a redirect.  AFAIK, the only way to that without some sort of web application logic is with javascript, which a user could just disable if they wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

when user clicks link on a.html to go to b.html, save a flag in database(using javascript for click -> database for save ). On loading b.html, first check the flag(database for retrieval -> javascript to check), if untrue, go back to a.html, else show b.html.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your users would move from page a to b. What you could do is instead of clicking a link going to page-b have a button.
Then that button can be part of a form with a hidden value... and check on page-b if that value was posted if not then redirect to page-a for example.
page-a:

```
<form action="b.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="a_submit" value="Go to page b">
</form>
```

top of page-b:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['a_submit'])){
///they came from page a
}else{
header('Location:a.html');
}
?>
```

With these two pieces of code you can implement exactly what you wanted. The only catch is you have to rename your b.html to b.php this is because only php files can handle php scripts. But do not worry there is no down side of using a php file instead of html; they act exactly the same but they only also allow php scripts to be ran.

Comment: Also if you have never used php before you can just add the php-code above your html stuff ex: <?php //my script stuff/// ?><html><head></head><body></body></html>